# Selective replace string in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, vector, replace

I have a vector of strings.  Most of the elements in the vector consist of one or more letters followed by one or more numbers. I wish to selectively replace only the words with "September" (and its abbreviations) in each string with "Sep" but retain the numbers.
This is what I have tried out using stringr package

```r
my.data <- c("01Sept2019", "05sep2019", "4September2019", "8sep2019",
              "12oct2019", "4Jun2018", "17Mar2017", "09May2015", "13Sep19")

library(stringr)    
my.data %>% str_replace_all("(?i)Sept?(ember)?[0-9]", "Sep") 
#>  [[1]]
#>    [1] "01Sep019", "05Sep019", "4Sep019", "8Sep019", "13Sep9"
```

This is what I would like to obtain:

```
#> [1] "01Sep2019", "05Sep2019", "4Sep2019", "8Sep2019", "13Sep19"
```

Can someone please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *base* you can use `sub` with the pattern `[Ss]ep[[:alpha:]]*` to find *September and its abbreviations* and replace it with `Sep`.

```
sub("[Ss]ep[[:alpha:]]*", "Sep", my.data)
#[1] "01Sep2019" "05Sep2019" "4Sep2019"  "8Sep2019"  "12oct2019" "4Jun2018" 
#[7] "17Mar2017" "09May2015" "13Sep19"
```

To match really only *September* followed by a number you can use:

```
sub("sep(t|(?=\\d))(e|(?=\\d))(m|(?=\\d))(b|(?=\\d))(e|(?=\\d))(r|(?=\\d))"
  , "Sep", my.data, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "01Sep2019" "05Sep2019" "4Sep2019"  "8Sep2019"  "12oct2019" "4Jun2018" 
#[7] "17Mar2017" "09May2015" "13Sep19"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
my.data %>% 
    str_replace("(?i)(Sep[^0-9]+)", "Sep")
```

Answer (score 0):

in Base-R

```
grep("Sep|sep",my.data,value=T)
```

output

```
[1] "01Sept2019"     "05sep2019"      "4September2019" "8sep2019"      
[5] "13Sep19"
```

Comment: Thanks, the data I put forth is sample from an array. There are various permutations for the spelling of september. Thats why I used (?i)Sept?(ember)?